# SUMIF with multiple criteria over varied ranges

Tags: vba, indexing, match, sumifs

```
Estimate #1                                         Estimate #2 
11/2/15                                             12/29/15    
QTY      Value                                      QTY     Value    
5.00     $4,800.00                               2.00    $1,920.00 
2.00     $3,950.00                               5.00    $9,875.00 
3.00     $30.00                                      8.00    $80.00 
5.00     $70.00                                      7.00    $98.00 
4.00     $480.00                                     9.00    $1,080.00
```

I have this example of a sheet of data that users will be inputting data. I need be able to get the sum of all the data based on if the estimates fall in the same month and if they are in the column matching the header "QTY". The problem is the QTY columns wont be in the same constant offset from one another.

I need either some VBA or a SUMIF type function, I know there are many posts about this but I can't seem to find the one I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I found this link useful http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/383395-sumifs-using-column-row-criteria.html (Apr 9th, 2009, 11:29 PM #3
Peter_SSs  Peter_SSs is offline, MrExcel MVP, Moderator), however more for formulas, rather than some vba code. Still, often when I sumif with vba I use if then statements to set it up. Also, you could use a pass the values into an array and then insert the array and then worksheetfunction.sum the array.